Drawing a smooth signals with ringing effect
I want to draw a graph like the green waveform below:

I tried with pen tool and then tried to smooth the nodes but it looks very bad :) specially
it does not contain the smooth transition from 0 to maximum value:

I would love to know what tools and methods can be used for such task?

You can use the pen tool for this.  Trace over the raster image using it as a guide. Adjust the curve handles. Something like this

In Inkscape it's easy to let the program draw the right curve, because  Extension > Render > Function plotter allows you to input the curve as math formula. Your attached example hints you know the right formulas. The function plotter accepts Python language math expressions. The next image is the plot of a randomly written expression. Its not any response of any known system.
The axis colors are afterwards changed to black:

Useful to know:

one should start by drawing the XY plot area as a rectangle
to avoid redrawing attempts + error messages + crashing the plotter turn Preview OFF before you try to edit the function expression. If you forget this and the plotter happens to crash you can continue by closing and restarting the plotter extension.
the result can be converted to editable paths by applying Path > Break Apart
You may need hundreds of sample points. It generates a curve with hundreds of nodes. That's no harm. Path > Simplify can be used to reduce the number of the nodes afterwards. Apply it only once to keep the curve visually close the plotted one.
You can well plot only some tricky part of a curve and draw the rest manually
There's also available an extension to draw parametric curves where X and Y are both functions of parameter t.

Nice looking curves which present functions qualitatively are easy to draw by using the pen in B-Spline mode (it's in the option bar)

It can be edited with the node tool without converting it to a path. For example make the effective delay more obvious:

You can draw a series of guide boxes for the pen cliks if you need a constant looking ringing frequency and exponential looking decay:

Turn a spline to ordinary path which has normal Bezier handles by applying Path > Object to Path, if needed. For example joining curves and scaling causes easily annoying side effects if you do not at first make the splines ordinary paths.

wow thanks a lot for the effort :) I have now mastered the art of sinusoidal waves :D
